# Get the ID after WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types

I used WP_Query to find posts of a certain criteria and loop through them performing actions. I grabbed the post id in the loop and assigned it to a variable `$i` to perform functions on.

Before the loop I used `get_the_id()` and it correctly displays the custom post page ID I am on. After the loop I used it again but this time it finds the id of the post I searched for.

*Why does this happen?*

```
function display_meta_box( $category ) 
{
    if (in_array('case_studies', get_post_types()))
    {

//get_the_id() - works fine here

        $combo_case_studies = esc_html( get_post_meta( $category->ID, 'cat', true ) ); 

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies');  
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        $i = '';

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            if ($combo_case_studies == get_the_title()) 
            {
                $i = get_the_id(); // correct?
            }

        endwhile;

...do stuff using $i...

//get_the_id() - gets a different ID

    }
}
```

I'm thinking of scrapping $i in its current implementation and instead doing this, but it still raises the question am I performing this loop correctly? And why is the page ID still different even after the loop?

```
function display_meta_box( $category ) 
{
        if (in_array('case_studies', get_post_types()))
        {

        $orig_i = get_the_id()


        ...loop stuff...


        ...use $orig_i keeping the ID from the get_the_id() before the loop...

        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to get the ID from the current page, you should make use of [`get_queried_object_id()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/) which will return the ID of the current queried object.

A new instance of `WP_Query` alters the `$post` global variable, that is why after your loop you'll see the value of the last post from your custom query if you a `var_dump($post);`

This is why it is so important to reset **all** new instances of `WP_Query` as it does change the variables. To do this, just add `wp_reset_postdata();` after your custom loop

Remember, if you need a counter, there is a build in loop counter, `$current_post` which you can access in your case via `$loop->current_post`. Just remember, this counter starts at `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after the while loop, this will reset your custom query data, so that you can retrieve the actual post/page data.